# Will sandbox environments store a SF user's push notification connection token?

Tags: connected-apps, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

I have pushed a connected app to a sandbox (test.salesforce.com). The connected app is for a Mobile App we have developed for iOS. In our dev environments it is recording and saving the connection token for the users who have logged into the iOS app, and associating the correct token for the Push Notification Registration for the user.

Now that we are testing in the sandbox environment, it is no longer storing the connection token. Is this functionality even turned on in the Sandbox?